# Extending Interfaces in Go

Tags: go, thrift, scribe

Fairly new to go. I'm trying to modify this go scribe server implementation:

https://github.com/samuel/go-thrift/blob/master/examples/scribe_server/main.go

I'd like to pass a channel to the `Log()` func so I can pass scribe data to a separate go routine but I'm not sure how to modify [`scribe/thrift.go`](https://github.com/samuel/go-thrift/blob/master/examples/scribe/thrift.go) to extend the log interface to be

```
Log(messages []*scribe.LogEntry, counts chan string)
```

(or whether this is even needed and if there is some way to extend the interface without messing with the original library).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't modify or extend an already declared interface, you can only create a new one, possibly
extending the old one. But you cannot re-declare methods in the interface.

This means that what you want to do (modify the `Scribe` interface so that its `Log` method has a different signature) is not possible.

What you can do is to have a type which holds your channel and [embeds](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) the structure you want to extend.

Example:

```
type Scribe interface {
    Log(Messages []*LogEntry) (ResultCode, error)
}

type ModifiedScribe struct {
    Scribe
    counts chan string
}

func (m *ModifiedScribe) Log(Messages []*LogEntry) (ResultCode, error) {
    // do something with m.counts

    // call embedded implementation's Log message
    return m.Scribe.Log(Messages)
}
```

The example above defines a struct which embeds a `Scribe` and defines its own `Log` method,
utilizing the one of the embedded `Scribe`. This struct can be used wherever a `Scribe` 
is expected (as it implements the `Scribe` interface) but holds your additional channel.